# Submitting pig jobs (in MRv1 mode) to Mapr yarn framework

Tags: apache-pig, hadoop-yarn, mapr

How do I submit pig jobs to the Mapr yarn framework. Any properties file changes required?

Do I have to alter Pig scripts running in MRv1 mode?

Answer (score 1):

The latest pig release supports YARN. Run the normal install.

http://doc.mapr.com/display/components/Pig+0.12.0-1408+Release+Notes